# Replicate table with instrumental variables approach from economics paper in R

Tags: r, instrumental-variables

I am trying to replicate Table 11 of the paper of Glaeser et al. (2004) "[Do institutions cause growth?](https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/shleifer/files/do_institutions_cause_growth.pdf)" in R.

[image]

(And I'm quite new to the world of R)
I was already able to reproduce the first stage regressions of panel B with the same results as the authors. However, I don't understand how to continue to the second stage. And also how to achieve the row "F-Test for excluded instruments". As I understood in the paper the tested instruments are log settler mortality and log population density in 1500.
The approach below I found on my research but somehow I don't get results that can help me. Maybe you know code that works better or can clarify what step I should take next to complete the second stage in panel A.

```
# perform the first stage regression the first column
s1 <- lm( ec~ sop + logsm + flo, data = data11) 
#I shortened the names of the variables for a better overview

coeftest(s1, vcov = vcovHC, type = "HC1") #don't know if I even need this for the replication
var.test(logsm, logpd, data = data11) #maybe this is wrong as well...
```